# Using the WebApiContrib ProtoBufFormatter on the Client Side

Tags: asp.net-web-api, protobuf-net

I'm using the WebApiContrib.Formatting.ProtoBuf NuGet package (http://nuget.org/packages/WebApiContrib.Formatting.ProtoBuf/0.9.5.0) to add support for Protocol Buffers in my Web API project.

The server side seems to work great, but I've been unable to get the Web API Client libraries to deserialize a server response.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[WebAPITest1.Protocol.Messages.Product, WebAPITest1.Protocol.Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

Here is my client code:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:60500/");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-protobuf"));
var response = httpClient.GetAsync("/api/products?$orderby=Name").Result;
Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);

var products = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>(new[]{new ProtoBufFormatter()}).Result;
Assert.IsTrue(products.Count() > 0);
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with something *other* than `IEnumerable<Product>`? In particular, maybe a top-level object that *has* a set of `Product`s ? For example:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class NeedsBetterName {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

That *might* be happier. Actually, I added better support for "naked enumerables" earlier this month (in r629) - however, I have not yet deployed this build anywhere.

Comment: This did indeed work, although in my case I'm trying to expose an OData endpoint. At least using Web API, I'm not sure how to tell Web API to encapsulate the results in a container class like this. Any idea when you'll be making this feature publicly available?

Comment: @RMD I'm working remotely this week without access to my usual VMs for clean build / regression testing; I can run a proper build next week

Comment: Great! Thanks Marc. We are just at the start of a new project, and are excited to offer protobuf as an option.

Comment: any update on this? I'm sure you're a busy guy, so sorry to bug you.

Comment: Just grabbed your latest version, and the issue is resolved. Thanks @Marc!